# Why are PAR1 and PAR2 on X-chromosome not matching the mother for a son?

Tags: x-dna

In a gene test for a son and a mother by FamilyTreeDNA, the son is shown as having a match with the mother on the X chromosome from about 2 700 000 to about 154 900 000, indicating that parts of the PAR1 and PAR2 are not matching.

What is the reason for this?

Answer (score 1):

In the Abstract of the article [The Human Pseudoautosomal Region (PAR): Origin, Function and Future](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2435358/), authors A Helena Mangs and Brian J Morris say:

> The pseudoautosomal regions (PAR1 and PAR2) of the human X and Y
> chromosomes pair and recombine during meiosis. Thus genes in this
> region are not inherited in a strictly sex-linked fashion. PAR1 is
> located at the terminal region of the short arms and PAR2 at the tips
> of the long arms of these chromosomes.

Figure 1 in the article [The human pseudoautosomal regions: a review for genetic epidemiologists](https://www.nature.com/articles/ejhg200863) by Antonia Flaquer, Gudrun A Rappold, Thomas F Wienker & Christine Fischer published in the *European Journal of Human Genetics* volume 16, pages771–779 (2008) shows the PAR1 and PAR2 regions on the human X and Y chromosomes.

The X and Y chromosomes can recombine during meiosis, but only at their tips.   The non-matching regions are usually very small, and are usually not useful for genetic genealogy.

Resources:

- Wikipedia : [Pseudoautosomal region](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudoautosomal_region)
- ISOGG Wiki: [Abbreviations](https://isogg.org/wiki/Abbreviations)
- FTDNA Forum: [Could an X-match be an Y-match?](https://forums.familytreedna.com/forum/the-x-chromosome/x-dna-basics/21964-could-an-x-match-be-an-y-match)
- hhmi Biointeractive (video): [Recombination of the Y Chromosome](https://www.biointeractive.org/classroom-resources/recombination-y-chromosome)
- DNA-Explained: [X Chromosome Master Class](https://dna-explained.com/2023/03/28/x-chromosome-master-class/)

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I still do not understand. Meiosis occurs before fertilization, so the Y chromosome is irrelevant. All the genetic material in the X chromosome should come from the mother, so there should be, barring spontaneous mutations or read errors, a 100 % match of the X chromosome for a son to his mother. No?

Comment: @a20 I'm not satisfied with this answer, either. I wanted to give you something to start with while we're waiting for a better answer.